# What should you name filename parts?

Tags: language-agnostic, naming-conventions

If I've got a file:

```
/home/dean/my-file.txt
```

What would you name the following parts:

```
1) /home/dean/
2) my-file.txt
3) my-file
4) /home/dean/my-file.txt
```

I've encountered (and written) much to much code where any of the above might be named 'file' or 'filename' or 'filepath' or 'filenameAndPath', etc.

Answer (score 0):

PHP's [pathinfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) function names them as follows:

```
[dirname] => /home/dean/
[basename] => my-file.txt
[extension] => txt
[filename] => my-file
```

Comment: I don't like this convention though because I would never consider the 'filename' to not include the extension...